# Is there any general interfaces on android to simulate mouse movements and click?

Tags: android, mouse

The image is like this we do the acion of moving and touching on one Android phone to control the other Android phone's mouse ancion.

I have got some sample about how to simulate mouse movements and click on linux,but I'd like to implement it on Android. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for test reasons, you can try [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) for this purpose. It's very useful testing tool.